# Deriving the type of ((.) foldr)

Tags: haskell, types, unification

I'm trying to manually derive the type of ((.) foldr)

```
(.) ::(b1 -> c1) -> (a1 -> b1) -> a1 -> c1
foldr :: (a2 -> b2 -> b2) -> b2 -> [a2] -> b2
```

Then:

```
b1 = a2 -> b2 -> b2
c1 = b2 -> [a2] -> b2
```

Matching the types I get:

```
((a2 -> b2 -> b2) -> (b2 -> [a2] -> b2)) -> (a1 -> (a2 -> b2 -> b2)) -> a1 -> (b2 -> [a2] -> b2)
```

But then I get confused on how to reduce this expresion.

Any help?

Thansks,
Sebastián.

Comment: The title of this questions asks about `(foldr (.))`, but in the actual question you use `((.) foldr)`. Please edit so they agree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your correctly figured out the type of the `(.)` in `(.) foldr`. The `(.)` is applied to one argument (the `foldr`) so you can throw away the `((a2 -> b2 -> b2) -> (b2 -> [a2] -> b2))` and what remains is the type of `(.) foldr`:

```
(a1 -> a2 -> b2 -> b2) -> a1 -> (b2 -> [a2] -> b2)
```

Make sure that `foldr` can have type `((a2 -> b2 -> b2) -> (b2 -> [a2] -> b2))` before you throw it away. If you got the matching right, this check cannot fail, but it is a good sanity check.

Answer (score 1):

If we have

```
(.)   :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> (a -> c)
foldr :: (x -> y -> y) -> y -> [x] -> y
```

Then for `(.) foldr`, the `b -> c` has to line up with the type of `foldr`, so

```
b             -> c
(x -> y -> y) -> (y -> [x] -> y)
```

Which implies

```
b ~ (x -> y -> y)
c ~ (y -> [x] -> y)
```

So substituting back in:

```
--                 b                       c
(.) foldr :: (a -> (x -> y -> y)) -> (a -> (y -> [x] -> y))
```

Since `->` is left associative, we can drop the extra parentheses:

```
(.) foldr :: (a -> x -> y -> y) -> (a -> y -> [x] -> y)
```

And if you want you can go a step further with

```
(.) foldr :: (a -> x -> y -> y) -> a -> y -> [x] -> y
```

So if we ask GHCi what the type is, we get

```
> :t (.) foldr
(.) foldr :: (a -> a1 -> b -> b) -> a -> b -> [a1] -> b
```

Where `a ~ a`, `a1 ~ x`, and `b ~ y`, so we've arrived at the correct answer.